# Is there any way to implement mouseleave() in ng5-slider in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, typescript

I want add mouseleave() to ng5-slider. Any suggestions please tell.

`<ng5-slider [(value)]="sliderVal" [(highValue)]="sliderHigh" [options]="sliderOpt"></ng5-slider>`

I want something like:

`<ng5-slider [(value)]="sliderVal" [(highValue)]="sliderHigh" [options]="sliderOpt" (mouseleave)="func()"></ng5-slider>`